# Tools to assess WiFi network security

Tags: security, wifi

It does focus on different areas of WiFi security:

Monitoring: Packet capture and export of data to text files for further processing by third party tools.
Attacking: Replay attacks, deauthentication, fake access points and others via packet injection.
Testing: Checking WiFi cards and driver capabilities (capture and injection).
Cracking: WEP and WPA PSK (WPA 1 and 2).

Comment: And for what OS? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: For Linux/Unix @Izzy !

Comment: OK, and now the price margin? Or should "Linux" implicate "gratis" (no money involved) or even "FOSS" (free & open software)?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) as a "tool set" to perform testing (and as a learning tool). It comes with over 600 pre-installed penetration-testing programs "out of the box" so to speak, and there is an active user community behind it that may give you some support options while you're in learning mode. If you want a more or less independent summary of Kali Linux, you can read this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux).

Kali Linux doesn't have to run on a dedicated machine; there are VMs available for vmware and vbox from their [download page](https://www.kali.org/downloads/). They've also ported it to run on ARM processors (e.g. Raspberry Pi, Beaglebone, etc) so you can use it as an "appliance" if that suits your needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you take me list of tools because I can't download Kali Linux for slow internet ! Thank in advance !

Comment: @Denny00 list-type questions are off the limits here ;) See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154).